# Convert String to Character Array? and Retrieve

Tags: android, arrays, string, char, character

How do I create a character array from a string? for example, say I have the string "Hello World"

1. How would I convert it to a character array?
2. Once converted, how do I retrieve each individual letter one by one?

My code:

```
public Character[] toCharacterArray(String s) {

    if (s == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Character[] array = new Character[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        array[i] = new Character(s.charAt(i));
    }

    return array;
}
```

Now if the above was implemented, how would I retrieve the returned character and how would I output it in an edit text box? using `outputBox.setText();` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a homework question, so I'm only going to give hints.

> 1) How would I convert it to a charterer array?

You've already done that!!  However:

- it would possibly be better if either you used a `char[]` instead of a `Character[]`, and
- if you do continue to use a `Character`, then it is better to use `Character.valueOf(...)` instead of `new Character(...)`.

> 2) once converted how do I retrieve each and individual letter 1 by 1?

Use a `for` loop.  It is one of the standard Java statements.  Refer to your Java textbook, tutorial, lecture notes ...

> ... how would i output it in an edit text box... using outputbox.setText(????)

Use `static Character.toString(char)`, or `Character.toString()` to create a String, depending on the type you have used.  You can then pass that as an argument to `setText` ...

---

For details of the methods I mentioned above, read [the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html).

Comment: I'm getting multiple errors trying to put what you said into practice, can you please add an example? Thanks

Comment: Sorry no.  You need to learn how to solve those errors yourself.  It is part of "learning how to program in Java".  And that applies whether or not this is "homework"!!

Answer (score 3):

you can convert a `String` to `Char` array simply using `toCharArray()` method...

```
char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
```

So, your updated method should be as follows...

```
public char[] toCharacterArray(String s) {

    char[] array = s.toCharArray();

    return array;
}
```

Comment: how do I output the returned value of the method? I can't 'textView.setText(char[]);' ... can I?

Comment: @sudoman The `setText()` method expects a `String`, nothing else. You must convert your result (whatever it is) to a `String` before passing it to `setText()`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to a simple char array like this:

```
String test = "hello";
char[] chars = test.toCharArray();
```

Then you can output any particular char in the array like this:

```
outputbox.setText(String.valueOf(chars[i]);
```